# Evaluation of limit with confusing moment

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Evaluate the following limit:

$\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{2\cos ^{-3}x\cdot\sin x}{2\sin x+x\cdot \cos x}\color {\blue}{=}\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{2\cos ^{-3}x}{2++x\cdot \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}}$ but $$\lim \limits_{x\to 0}x\cdot \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}=1$$ then $\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{2\cos ^{-3}x}{2++x\cdot \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}}=\frac{2}{3}.$ Right?

But I have one question. In the second equality I divide enumerator and denominator to $\sin x$. Does it legal? What about if $\sin x=0$? Can anyone explain it to me please?

Comment: As you consider $x \to 0$, this means that $x$ is more and more closed to $0$, but is **not equal to** $0$. Thus here $\sin x \neq0$, it is legal to cancel the factor. Please check the value of the limit, it is $2/3$, no?

Comment: what does $2/(2+1)$ equal?

Comment: @OlivierOloa, Sorry! Answer is $2/3$. Thank you very much for you excellent answer!

Comment: @RaheemNajib You are welcome! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you consider $x \to 0$, this means that $x$ is more and more close to $0$, but is **not equal to** $0$. Thus here $\sin x \neq0$, and you are allowed to cancel it as a factor. Please check the value of the limit, it should be $2/3$.

Comment: $x$ is not equal to zero since we consider deleted neighborhood of $0$. Right?

Comment: by definition of limit of function.

Comment: Thank you very much, dear Olivier!

Answer (score 0):

Since, $x\ne 0$ hence, one can also cancel $x$ as factor in numerator & denominator   $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos^{-3}x\cdot \sin x}{2\sin x+x\cdot \cos x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos^{-3}x\cdot \frac{\sin x}{x}}{2\frac{\sin x}{x}+\cos x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\sin x}{x}}{2\frac{\sin x}{x}+\cos x}\left(\frac{1}{\cos x}\right)^3$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\cdot 1+1}\left(1\right)^3=\color{red}{\frac{2}{3}}$$